# Refresh page data when button is clicked inside a usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page which displays data from a web service. It first checks if the data exists in session, and then gets it from the WS if not.

My control calls the web service and adds another row to the data (an SP list in this case). If the new item was added successfully, I want to refresh the list in session. If not, no refresh is needed.

I want the page to get the new data from the web service, even if the data exists in session.
My problem is that the event handler for the button fires after the page load event of the page containing the control, where the data is retrieved and bound to a repeater.

I was thinking of using some client side tricks, like checking the event target or checking for a button name in the post params list, but my button is a server side control, and I would like it to remain that way.

Is there some best practice solution for this type of situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing in binding the data in the PreRender event handler. This way I raise the flag in the click event handler, and since the PreRender happens after the click event handler, I can check if the flag is raised, and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Page_Load()
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
         //call initial databind functions
         MyDataBindStuff();
    }
    else
    {
         //this is a postback, you may or may not want to do anyting
    }
}

private void MyDataBindStuff()
{
    //do databind work
}


void yourBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //do work
   //now databind if needed after do work
   MyDataBindStuff();

}
```